# When reviewing Suggested Edits queue, how to "improve" the suggested edit?

Tags: support, design, user-interface, suggested-edits

I came across a tag-edit that I wanted to improve slightly, while reviewing the *Suggested Edits* queue. At the top of the page it says, "*Approve, reject, or **improve** edits suggested by users.*"

I see no way, from that dialog, to improve the edit, e.g., to edit either the original or the suggested-edit tag description.

Clicking `More` didn't help. It showed only this additional text:

> - Approve edits that clearly improve the post
> - Reject edits that fail to improve the post or that make it worse
> - Skip if you are not sure and want to go to the next suggested edit

What am I missing?

[image: This is the suggested-edit I was reviewing]

Comment: Hi, Drew. I went to the same question and saw the three buttons shown in your screenshot plus 'Improve Edit' (or something similar). When I clicked that option, I was free to alter the edited form of the tag description further. Evidently, Stack Exchange treats the the Improve Edit option for tag wikis as an advanced privilege requiring 20,000 reputation points, although  I'm not sure why it adopted so high a number for that particular action. See this page on "[Trusted User](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)" status for more on the 20,000-point threshold.

Comment: @SvenYargs: I see. I wondered about that. That explains it. But the intro should be changed in that case - it should not, for uses without the possibility to edit, say "*Approve, reject, or improve edits suggested by users.*". And I think probably I was all the more confused about not finding how to edit because on some other SE sites I do have that privilege. I think there is a (minor) UI bug here.

Answer (score 2):

To "improve" edit suggestions, you need the privilege to edit posts, requiring no peer review.

For editing questions and answers, the privilege is granted at 2k reputation.

But for editing tag wikis, it's different. To approve or reject suggestions from others, 5k is required. To singlehandedly edit tags, or to "improve" suggestions, you need the "trusted user" privilege, granted to you at 20k.

See also: [Edit tag wikis, at 20k](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), [Approve tag wiki edits, at 5k](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) and [Edit questions and answers, at 2k](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: Yes, thanks; @SvenYargs said that in his comment. That's fine, but in that case there is a bug in the UI. It should not say "*Approve, reject, or **improve** edits*" for a user who does not have the privilege of improving.